# Found ERROR when run ng-serve when i am installing node module in existing project

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am encountering a problem when I run ng serve

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\Desktop\my project\default\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\Desktop\my project\default\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\Desktop\my project\default\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Muhammad Waqas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
  See "C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-Rv4bIL\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I want to run project successfully please help me guys